# How to efficiently find out all clusters of a given size $k$ in an undirected graph?

Tags: graph-theory

For example, in an undirected graph as follows, I want to find out all clusters of size 4. How should I do it efficiently?

As for a cluster, points should be connected. For example {1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,13},{1,2,3,14},{1,2,14,17},{1,14,16,17} are clusters; while {1,2,4,13}, {1,2,4,14} are not clusters because the four points in a cluster are not connected (i.e. there are isolated tree(s)/node(s)).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your term "clusters" is improper.  You're seeking either *complete subgraphs* (i.e., subgraphs of size $4$ where each vertex is connected to all the others) or *connected subgraphs* (i.e., subgraphs of size $4$ that are connected).  None of my dozen or so books on graph theory mention this novel use of "cluster" (nor this novel use of "pivot").

Anyway....

In *Mathematica*:

```
g = RandomGraph[{30, 100}, VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image]

The potential subsets of four vertices:

```
subs = Subsets[Range[30], {4}];
```

Check all these subgraphs to see which are *complete* subgraphs (of size $4$):

```
Select[
      Table[
      Subgraph[g, subs[[i]], 
      VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
      {i, Length[subs]}],
   CompleteGraphQ]
```

[image: complete subgraphs of size 4]

If instead you are looking for merely *connected* subgraphs, then the last function should be:

```
Select[
          Table[
          Subgraph[g, subs[[i]], 
          VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
          {i, Length[subs]}],
       ConnectedGraphQ]
```

The above code is certainly efficient enough for your task.  For the graph above, all connected subgraphs of size $4$ were found in 1.54531 seconds on a Mac laptop.  For a random graph with $40$ vertices and $150$ edges, all $7068$ connected 4-subgraphs were found in less than a minute.

---

It is very unclear whether the OP allows (non-tree) subgraphs of size four connected in a loop, such as this:

[image]

Comment: I think here "cluster" means *connected* (but not necessarily complete) subgraph.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Finding the "subgraph" is actually very redundant, besides,  RobPratt is correct that the "complete graph" doesn't fulfill my "cluster" requirement. For example, in my graph, {1,2,3,4} is a cluster, but it's not a "complete graph". As for the "ConnectedGraph", if I'm not wrong with the concept, it will get a lot of subgraphs with the same vertices. However, I just need the unique sets of vertices that are connected. For example, {2,3,13,14} can form several connected graphs with different connecting edges.

Comment: My algorithm idea to solve this problem is as follows. Regarding each point as a pivot, then enumerate all pivots (loop start): based on the pivot find out the cluster of given size from the remaining graph, then delete the pivot(and its edges) from the graph(loop end) for the sake of efficiency for the following loops.
For a Delaunay triangulation graph of 100 random points, my algorithm can get the clusters of size 4 in about 0.5s (CPU: i5-4210U) given the connection 0-1 matrix. However, if the cluster size is a bit bigger, let's say 10, then my algorithm sucks.

Comment: Six How:  Gosh... not even an upvote for my solution (which works efficiently on large networks)?  I think your proposed algorithm will fail once you start deleting "pivots."

Comment: Sorry bro, your computational time is much worse than mine, especially given that I'm computing on an almost archaic CPU(i5-4210U). I said for a random graph of 100 points (674 edges for a specific case), my computing time is just 0.5s.

Comment: Six How:  Have you validated your algorithm?  It appears that deleting "pivots" will lead to incorrect answer (finding too few connected subgraphs).  Of course it will *speed* the algorithm... but so what?  Your mis-use of standard terms from graph theory (e.g., your persistence in using the incorrect "clusters" after your error has been pointed out to all) adds to my worry that your algorithm is actually correct.

Comment: Why can't deleting pivots find all subgraphs? Take your "Linear" graph for example, selecting point 1 as the pivot will get {7,1,6,3,},{2,7,1,6},{5,2,7,1}. After deleting point 1, the point 2 will be selected as the pivot and get {4,5,2,7}. After deletiing point 2, there will be no more cluster of size 4.

Comment: BTW, why do you insist on using the improper standard term(subgraph) as RobPratt and I both pointed out the standard term(subgraph) doesn't meet the requirement of "cluster". The most relevant standard term is not "subgraph", but "tree". All points in a "cluster" must be able to form a tree in the graph. However they can form more than one tree if they are not "linearly" connected in the graph as your "Linear" example shows.

Comment: @Six How:  So you do not want to include four vertices connected in a loop?

Comment: @David G. Stork:  It doesn't matter whether the four vertices form a loop. For example, the cluster{1,2,3,14}, you can consider the connection as 1-2-3-14-1, or 1-2-14-3.